# TFS2010 Team build - waiting for an "InvokeProcess" step to complete

Tags: build-process

I am performing a database restore as part of our TFS 2010 Team build. Since a number of databases are being restored, I am using a batch file which is invoked via the InvokeProcess activity.
I have a number of issues that I am uncertain about:
1. Does the TFS wait for all the command in the batch file to complete or move to the next activity as soon as kicking the InvokeProcess?
2. Is there a way to have the build process wait for successful completion of the batch command?

I am using it as follows:
The FileName property of InvokeProcess has "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
The Arguments property has the full path of my batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the InvokeProcess will wait for the external command to finish.